# Firebase returning null as first value

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am kind of new to Firebase. I am using it in one of my small projects. I create a users node on db when a user registers and add its info under it with the uid being the id of the object. It looks similar to the following.

```
users
    $uid
        email = "xyz@xyz.com"
```

When i try to run a transaction block on that node to add/update some stuff Xcode prints out following result. Since this can't be cast to dictionary code fails. When i try to export my data out of firebase there are no null values. I saw similar questions to this when numeric ids are used which is not the case here. I just can't figure out what is wrong.
Any help is appreciated...

```
Optional(<null>)
Optional({
    email = "xyz@xyz.com";
})
```

Comment: I was using runTransactionBlock method. Turns out this method is called multiple times. When i properly handled that I managed to save my data.

Comment: Accept(tick mark top left part of my answer) my answer if it solved your issue, i have suggested multiple options. :) Happy Coding http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @user35012 Have you found any solution for this? I am facing same issue.

Comment: I noticed that this usually happens when you use either integer ids or enter data through admin console manually. So I deleted everything and I created a simple html page for simple cruds and for each data I insert, first I got a key from firebase. I stopped getting null values after that. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to resolve the issue:

1. Export the data (in JSON format)
2. Delete the existing data on Firebase Realtime Database.
3. Remove the null value from the exported JSON data (and refine it as needed).
4. Import the (refined) JSON into Firebase DB.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to append data to this node just :-

```
 let dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)
```

- You can do it by retrieving your `snapshot.value` as a `NSMutableDictionary`.

  ```
  dbRef.child("email").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {(list) in

              if let listDict = list.value as? NSMutableDictionary{

                  listDict.setObject(newValue, forKey: newKey)
                  dbRef.setValue(listDict)

              }
  ```

If you want to update your data you can either:-

- Run a `transactionBlock`:-

  ```
     dbRef.child("email").runTransactionBlock({ (data: FIRMutableData) -> FIRTransactionResult in
        // Set value and report transaction success
       data.value = "newEmail@gm.com"
       return FIRTransactionResult.successWithValue(data)
              }) { (error, committed, snapshot) in
               if let error = error {
                   print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
           }
  ```
- update the values :-

  ```
         dbRef.updateChildValues(["email" : "newEmail@gm.com"])
  ```